# Let A be some matrix and suppose x ∈kernel A(transpose) and y∈ Im(A). How to show that x and y are perpendicular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I sort of has problem with this question. I assigned a matrix and calculated the span of ImA and kerA(transpose). But no idea what to do after this ?

Comment: @ Samnip Dhital Were you given a specific matrix $A$ or was it a general one?

Comment: it was general one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y \in$ Im $A$, $\exists x_0$ s.t. $A x_{0}=y$.

We have,

$A^Tx = 0$

$\implies x^TA = 0$ (take transpose both sides)

$\implies x^TAx_0 = 0$ (right multiply both sides by $x_0$)

$\implies x^Ty = 0$

Comment: I didnot understand the first line of your answer.Can you please explain.

Comment: @SamipDhital if y is in the image of A, there is an $x_0$ in the domain that maps to y; this is true for any function and in particular is true for A.